# Facing an issue while loading values from one module to another module in verilog

Tags: verilog

In my Verilog code, I am trying to read some values from the memory module, and the output values of the memory module will be provided as input values to another module, `get_quantizer_output`, in which we will perform some calculations and determine our output based on the values that are loaded from the memory. My code is given below:

```
module memory
    #(
        parameter RAM_WIDTH         = 12,
        parameter RAM_ADDR_BITS     = 3,
        parameter INIT_START_ADDR   = 0,
        parameter INIT_END_ADDR     = 7
    )
    (
    input                           clock,
    input                           ram_enable,
    input                           write_enable,
    input       [RAM_ADDR_BITS-1:0] address,
    input       [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]     input_data,
    output reg  [RAM_WIDTH-1:0]     output_data
    );
    
   
   (* RAM_STYLE="BLOCK" *)
   reg [RAM_WIDTH-1:0] ram_name [(2**RAM_ADDR_BITS)-1:0];

   initial begin
      ram_name[0] = 12'b00000000000;
      ram_name[1] = 12'b00001000111;
      ram_name[2] = 12'b00010111011;
      ram_name[3] = 12'b00101110001;
      ram_name[4] = 12'b01001101100;
      ram_name[5] = 12'b01110100111;
      ram_name[6] = 12'b10110010110;
      ram_name[7] = 12'b11111010110;
   end

   always @(ram_enable or write_enable or address or input_data) begin
      if (ram_enable) begin
         if (write_enable)
            ram_name[address] = input_data;
         output_data = ram_name[address];
      end
    $display("output_data is %d", output_data);
   end

endmodule

module get_quantizer_output (clk, rst, ch_output, boundary_1, boundary_2, boundary_3, boundary_4, boundary_5, boundary_6, boundary_7, boundary_8, cluster_index_val);
  input clk, rst;
  
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_1;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_2;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_3;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_4;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_5;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_6;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_7;
  input wire [11:0]  boundary_8;
  

  input wire signed [11:0] ch_output;
  reg [11:0] ch_output_mag;
  output reg [3:0] cluster_index_val;
  

  
  always @(ch_output) begin
    if (ch_output[11] == 1) begin
      ch_output_mag = ~ch_output + 1; 
     
    end else begin
      ch_output_mag = ch_output;
    end
    
    $display("boundary_1 is %d", boundary_1);
    $display("boundary_2 is %d", boundary_2);
    $display("boundary_3 is %d", boundary_3);
    $display("boundary_4 is %d", boundary_4);
    $display("boundary_5 is %d", boundary_5);
    $display("boundary_6 is %d", boundary_6);
    $display("boundary_7 is %d", boundary_7);
    $display("boundary_8 is %d", boundary_8);
    
    
    if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_5) begin
      
      if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_3) begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_2) begin
         
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0111 : 4'b1000;
        end else begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0110 : 4'b1001;
        end
      end else begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_4) begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0101 : 4'b1010;
        end else begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0100 : 4'b1011;
          end
        end
     
    end else begin
      
      if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_7) begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_6) begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0011 : 4'b1100;
        end else begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0010 : 4'b1101;
        end
      end else begin
        
        if (ch_output_mag <= boundary_8) begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0001 : 4'b1110;
        end else begin
          
          cluster_index_val = (ch_output[11] == 1) ? 4'b0000 : 4'b1111;
        end
      end
    
    
    end 
    
    $display("cluster_index_val is %d", cluster_index_val);
  end
    
  
endmodule


module ibq (clk, rst, ch_output, cluster_index_out);

  input clk, rst;
  output [3:0] cluster_index_out;
  input wire signed [11:0] ch_output;

  
  wire [11:0] boundary1;
  wire [11:0] boundary2;
  wire [11:0] boundary3;
  wire [11:0] boundary4;
  wire [11:0] boundary5;
  wire [11:0] boundary6;
  wire [11:0] boundary7;
  wire [11:0] boundary8;
  
  
  
  memory memory1 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b000), .output_data(boundary1));
  memory memory2 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b001), .output_data(boundary2));
  memory memory3 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b010), .output_data(boundary3));
  memory memory4 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b011), .output_data(boundary4));
  memory memory5 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b100), .output_data(boundary5));
  memory memory6 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b101), .output_data(boundary6));
  memory memory7 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b110), .output_data(boundary7));
  memory memory8 (.clock(clk), .ram_enable(1'b1), .write_enable(1'b0), .address(3'b111), .output_data(boundary8));
  
 
  get_quantizer_output get_quantizer_output0 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .ch_output(ch_output), .boundary_1( boundary1), .boundary_2( boundary2), .boundary_3( boundary3), .boundary_4( boundary4), .boundary_5( boundary5), .boundary_6( boundary6), .boundary_7( boundary7), .boundary_8( boundary8), .cluster_index_val(cluster_index_out));
 

endmodule


module ibq_test (clk, rst, cluster_index_out);
  input clk, rst;
  output [3:0] cluster_index_out;
  wire signed [11:0] ch_output_test = 12'b101110011001;
  ibq ibq0 (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), .ch_output(ch_output_test), .cluster_index_out(cluster_index_out));


endmodule
```

The problem is that when I run this code, I get unexpected output that is given below:

```
boundary_1 is    x
boundary_2 is    x
boundary_3 is    x
boundary_4 is    x
boundary_5 is    x
boundary_6 is    x
boundary_7 is    x
boundary_8 is    x
cluster_index_val is  0
output_data is    0
output_data is   71
output_data is  187
output_data is  369
output_data is  620
output_data is  935
output_data is 1430
output_data is 2006
```

According to my expectations, first of all the values that we fetch from the memory module should be displayed and after this those values should again be printed because we are passing the output of the memory module to the `get_quantizer_output`. In the end, the output `cluster_index_val` should be printed. Can anyone guide me in this regard why I am observing this strange behaviour? It seems that the `get_quantizer_output` module is being triggered first although I have instantiated it after loading all the values from the memory module. Why my modules are being triggered in a wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

No time elapses in your simulation.  This means that all your display statements execute at time 0.  Typically, you would add delays in your testbench (for example to generate your clock signal), and you would allow your simulation to run for several clock cycles.

If you change all your `$display` statements to `$strobe`, then you likely will see the `x` values be replaced by the expected known data values that match your `output_data` values.

Since all the displays happen at the same time, the order of the statements is arbitrary.  All the `memory` modules are in parallel, and the simulator has the freedom to choose which statement is executed first.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 4.7 *Nondeterminism*.

Generally, you want to display signal values when they are stable, not when they are changing.  Time 0 is especially tricky in this regard.